# HighCharts - basic barchart not rendering in SharePoint ASPX page

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, sharepoint-2010

I have a simple basic barchart which does not render at all in SharePoint 2010 page (displays block white space).
I placed my code within content editor and used javascript files what are imported from High charts library (highcharts.js and exporting.js).

can somebody advise me in fixing the code and what should I do.
Here is the code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 1900',
        data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 2008',
        data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
    }]
   });
   });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; 
margin: 0 auto">         
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should put your reference to the highcharts.js before you actually use the code.

Comment: I tried to put it before the code but it is the same no chart rendering.

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the browser console?

Comment: no, I don't just empty page with neither chart info nor diagram.